# Error graphQl Expected {} to be a GraphQL schema

Tags: javascript, nodejs, graphql

Hola amigos tengo un error en graphQl recien lo estoy estudiando y me dio este error y no he podido soluicionarlo.

Versión de mi proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { graphqlHTTP } = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./graphql/schema");

const app = express();


app.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Welcome. Go to /graphql" }));

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server on port 3000");
})
```

schema.js

```
const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } = require("graphql");

const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "QueryType",
    description: "The root query type",
    fields: {
        hello: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            description: "return a string",
            resolve: () => "Hello Word"
        }
    }
})

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: QueryType
});

module.export = schema;
```

error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece un problema de dependencias, intenta hacer un downgrade de `graphql` a 14.7.0 o 15.3.0 e intenta otra vez, yo estoy usando `apollo-server-express` en vez de `express-graphql` por si quieres intentar de esa forma